# Finding rational points on a conic

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-geometry, algebraic-number-theory

I'm trying to find the rational points or prove there is no rational points on curve：
$$ 3x^2+5y^2=4$$
I write the equation as $3X^2+5Y^2=4Z^2$ ($X,Y,Z$ are integers having no common factor).

And I 've proved that $Z$ is divisible by $4$, neither $X$ nor $Y$ is divisible by $2$.

But I still cannot prove if there's any rational points, is there any rational points on that conic?

Comment: https://www1.cmc.edu/pages/faculty/lenny/nt_wrk_sem/legendre.pdf  look at 17.3.2  where you want  $3X^2 + 5 Y^2 = (2Z)^2  $

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume that $$4Z^2 = 3X^2+5Y^2\tag 1$$

with $(X, Y, Z)\neq(0,0,0)$ and, without loss of generality, that $\gcd(X, Y, Z) = 1$. Taking $(1)$ modulo 3:

$$Z^2 \equiv_3 -Y^2\tag 2$$

The only squares in $\Bbb Z/3\Bbb Z$ are $0$ and $1$, hence $(2)$ implies that $Z$ and $Y$ are 0 mod 3, i.e. they are multiples of 3, say $Z=3z$ and $Y=3y$.  Putting this in $(1)$ and dividing by 3:

$$12z^2 = X^2+15y^2 \tag 3$$

Taking $(3)$ mod 3 yields $X^2\equiv_3 0$ so that $X$ is a multiple of 3, too, and $3\mid \gcd(X,Y,Z)$ which was already excluded.  Hence the only solution of $(1)$ is $X=Y=Z=0$.